# Gzip Comporession and leverage Browser Cache Not working

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, cache, performance, htaccess

i am trying to optimize my store.

to optimize it i have added Gzip Code and Leverage Browser Cache Code in .htaccess File.

There are 2 .htaccess file on my server.  one is .htaccess and second is .htaccess.bak

both file have same code and Some 301 Redirect COdes.

inspite having Gzip and leverage Browser Cache Code in .htaccess  it is not working.

Following Gzip and Htaccess code i  have put in my .htaccess and .htaccess.bak file

```
    <ifModule mod_gzip.c>
   mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
  # compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

 # remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent

 ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
  ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
  </IfModule>
  ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

after adding this code i did check Gzip COmpression working or not.  Gtmetrixt, googlepagespeed  showing it is not working. also did check in gzipcomression Checker: http://checkgzipcompression.com/  it says compression in not enabled.

is there any setting in server or php that i should enable for Gzip COmpression to work.?

How to Fix it? Need HElp!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use following code in your .htaccess file which is in your Magento root directory

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     # YEAR
     <FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|flv|pdf)$">
          Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400"
     </FilesMatch>
     # WEEK
     <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf|woff)$">
         Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
     </FilesMatch>
     # 45 MIN
     <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|txt)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400"
     </FilesMatch>

     Header set Connection keep-alive

</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl|asp|html)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only file that matters is the "**.htaccess**" file in your root directory. The ".bak" is not used by the webserver.

I assume your server is running Apache? If not, those entries may not work.

The section "`<ifModule mod_gzip.c>`" is probably not needed, as that is redundant.

You can try enabling zlib.compression in php, as this can allow Magento pages to be compressed. In your .htaccess file:

```
php_flag zlib.output_compression on
```

See if that makes your pages compressed. The other compression settings you have should compress other files like JavaScript, CSS, etc...